# Openerp - need to remove 'Can be Sold' in Product Template form

Tags: product, openerp-7

I am new to OpenErp and I am customizing it.
In Product form, I need to remove **Can be Sold** field.  Because I am implementing it for only purchases.
I tried to remove the code through XML code (form view).  However, it is throwing error, since this field is mandatory by default.

Also, I want make **Can be Purchase** is the default field with by default checked.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to ur view file....

```
<record id="view_product_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">product.product.form</field>
        <field name="model">product.product</field>
        <field name="type">form</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_normal_form_view"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//div[@class='oe_title']" position="replace">
                <div class="oe_title">
                    <div class="oe_edit_only">
                        <label for="name" string="Product Name"/>
                    </div>
                    <h1>
                        <field name="name"/>
                    </h1>
                    <label for="categ_id" class="oe_edit_only"/>
                    <h2><field name="categ_id"/></h2>
                    <div name="options" groups="base.group_user">
                        <field name="sale_ok" invisible="1"/>
                        <label for="sale_ok" invisible="1"/>
                        <field name="purchase_ok"/>
                        <label for="purchase_ok"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
```

And this to ur py file....

from openerp.osv import osv
from openerp.osv import fields

class product_product(osv.osv):

```
_inherit = 'product.product'
_columns = {
    'purchase_ok': fields.boolean('Can be Purchased'),
}

_defaults = {
    'purchase_ok': 1,
}
product_product()
```

Comment: Hi Thank you so much for your quick help. You mean to inherit the products module with above code?

Comment: Thanks alot, I fixed it through your answer by using `invisible="1"` in `product.normal.form` and `product.template` forms.  You saved time.

Comment: ya one should always inherit existing modules and make changes rather than making direct changes in base code..